# Execute code at end of Module/Class, like Ruby test/unit

Tags: ruby

Ruby's unit testing framework executes unit tests even though nobody creates unit test object. For example,

in MyUnitTest.rb

```
require 'test/unit'

class MyUnitTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_true
        assert true
    end
end
```

and when i invoke that script as

```
ruby MyUnitTest.rb
```

test_true method gets executed automatically.  How is this done?

I am trying to come up with a framework that can do similarly.  I dont want "if __ FILE __ == $0" at the end of every module that uses my framework.

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Test::Unit` uses [at_exit](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/at_exit) for this, which runs code immediately before your application quits:

```
at_exit do
  puts "printed before quit"
end

.. other stuff
```

I don't think there is any way to run code specifically after a class or module definition is closed.

Comment: but you can redefine `Class.inherited` for your class to get references to all the subclasses, and then play with them in your `at_exit` hook.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Daniel Lucraft's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129495/execute-code-at-end-of-module-class-like-ruby-test-unit/1129727#1129727), you could define a finalizer guard to have some code run when the garbage collector runs:

```
ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(MyClass, lambda {
  puts "printed before MyClass is removed from the Object space"
})
```

But personally I think [`at_exit`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/at%5Fexit) is a better fit since its timing is a bit more deterministic.